# How to select a value from the dropdown using selenium, the values change as per selection and there are around 100 values in the dropdown

Tags: java, selenium

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bacA9.png)

```
<input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" id="procedureFields" required="" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiAutocomplete-input MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd MuiOutlinedInput-inputAdornedEnd" aria-autocomplete="list" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" value="">
```

Query - How to select a value from the dropdown using selenium, the values change as per selection and there are around 100 values in the dropdown.

I have tried using select and action class

```
    WebElement procCodes = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id = 'procedureFields']"));
    procCodes.click();
    Actions myAction = new Actions(driver); 
    myAction.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.DOWN, Keys.DOWN, Keys.ENTER)).build().perform();
```

Comment: Can you share page URL?

Comment: it's from the qa env. won't be accessible from outside.

Comment: Got some accessible env with same dropdown?

Comment: No. These are only predefined values for the field. but what made you think like this?

Comment: To reproduce the issue and if possible to resolve it.